# Is it possible to create a nested adapter in EmberJS?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Am I able to nest Ember Data adapters?

For example, say if I have a model `//models/site.js` with a template `//templates/site.hbs` and I want to make a custom `query()` request to `${ENV.APP.API_HOST}/customers/${org}/sites` - as per the docs I can simply customise the `query()` function at `//adapters/site.js`.

But what if I have a second template at `//templates/sites/show.hbs` and I need to query a second distinctly different endpoint such as `${ENV.APP.API_HOST}/customers/${org}/sites/${id}` (or any other deeply nested data endpoint) can I setup an adapter under `//adapters/sites/show.js`? I can't seem to achieve that with Ember Data currently.

Comment: are you trying to do this without using the router? because the router definitely does support multiple dynamics segments in a path. you have to nest the routes though. are you doing that? EDIT: apparently the router can accommodate multiple dynamic segments  without nesting -> http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/multiple-dynamic-segments-without-nesting/10311/3

Comment: The router has nested routes which dictate the URL structure in the app itself. But it's the endpoints I need. Eg. if the route is: /post/id/comment/id/custom-thing/id and I want the endpoint to be api/custom-things-with-a-stupid-name/id there's currently no easy way of doing that I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to customise and fix this by using an ember plugin - https://github.com/amiel/ember-data-url-templates/. It has good documentation and allows you to customise [URL segments](https://github.com/amiel/ember-data-url-templates/wiki/Custom-urlSegments).

My site adapter

```
// adapters/site.js
export default ApplicationAdapter.extend({
  urlTemplate: '{+host}/api/{apiVersion}v1/customers{/org}/sites{/site}',
  queryUrlTemplate: '{+host}/api/{apiVersion}v1/customers{/org}/sites'
});
```

And my service adapter

```
// adapters/service.js
export default ApplicationAdapter.extend({
  urlTemplate: '{+host}/api/{apiVersion}v1/customers{/org}/services{/service}',
});
```

Then in my routes I loaded params that were picked up by the URL segments in my adapters thanks to ember-data-url-templates. Using seperate queryRecord() calls with Ember store allowed me to specify the correct endpoints as required.

```
// routes/sites.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    let siteQuery = this.modelFor('sites');
    let org = siteQuery.customer_orgCode;
    return RSVP.hash({
      site: this.get('store').queryRecord('site', { org: org, site: params.site_id })
    });
  }
});

// routes/sites/show.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    let siteQuery = this.modelFor('sites');
    let org = siteQuery.customer_orgCode;
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      service: this.get('store').queryRecord('service', { org: org, service: params.instance_id })
    });
  }
});
```

NB // I've use an RSVP hash as there's likely to be multiple calls for the same model, but you can just `return` the `this.get` query as necessary directly to `model:` as well.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Ember doesn't support nested endpoints at the moment. Related discussions: [1](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/nested-urls-for-ember-datas-restadapter-proposal/5290), [2](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/current-way-to-handle-nested-resources/7477/8).